# Как реализовать поиск элементов по критериям в SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Есть три таблицы - `Item`, `Detail` и `DetailsItem`. Между собой они создают связь many-to-many. Каким образом можно реализовать поиск `Item` по определенным `Detail`.

Например, есть *молоток*. Он состоит из нескольких частей, таких как: *железо*, *дерево*, *медь*. Мне нужно найти этот молоток по деталям. Например, я вбиваю параметры такие как *дерево* и *медь* по которым точно найдется нужный элемент, но если я добавлю дополнительный параметр такой как *силикон*, то данный элемент отбрасывается.

Также по этим параметрам могут находиться другие элементы, которые содержат в себе железо, дерево и медь, но если один из параметров не совпадает, то элемент должен не отображаться в итоговой выборке.

```
SELECT item.idItem, detail.idDetail, detail.title FROM item 
JOIN details_item ON item.idItem = details_item.idItem 
JOIN detail ON detail.idDetail = details_item .idDetail 
WHERE detail.title in ("Железо","Дерево","Медь")
```

Данный запрос находит элементы в которых есть эти детали, но так же отображаются другие элементы, которые имеют совпадение материалов только 1 из 3.

Так же заранее неизвестно сколько будет параметров для поиска, так как в `in (...)` будет передаваться массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title
FROM item i
JOIN
(
  SELECT idItem, COUNT(idDetail) as qtyDetail
  FROM details_item di
  JOIN detail d
  ON di.idDetail = d.id
  WHERE title IN ('Медь', 'Олово')
  GROUP BY idItem
) q
ON i.id=q.idItem AND q.qtyDetail=2
```

В нём отдельно передаются наименования деталей (`'Медь', 'Олово'`) и отдельно - их количество (`2`)

Пример на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kuHQAAfscDYphxwkfaWLti/1)

Можно бы было посчитать количество переданных деталей прямо в запросе, но в этом случае либо пришлось бы городить передачу наименований в виде двухмерного массива `(('Медь'), ('Олово'))`, либо считать количество найденных id в таблице деталей.

Первый вариант - громоздок.

Второй вариант плох тем, что если бы мы передали несуществующую деталь, то она бы была просто отброшена, и запрос вернул бы данные по запрошенным существующим деталям - мне это кажется неправильным.